# How can I transform a categorical variable that is expressed in characters into a numerical categorical variable in R?

Tags: r, variables, replace, numbers, categorical-data

I have tried to turn my categorical variables into numbers (I want to replace these words with number, without specifying them one by one and specifying the number they should have):

```
abaz
 [1] " Crime"       " Animation"   " Drama"       " Comedy"      " Adventure"  

 [6] " Biography"   " Documentary" "character(0)" " Thriller"    " Fantasy"    

[11] " Action"     

> apply(abaz, 1, function(x) match(x, letters))
```

I get this error:

```
Error in apply(abaz, 1, function(x) match(x, letters)) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Comment: `as.numeric(as.factor(abaz))`

Comment: Are you trying to replace specific letters within a character with numbers? For example would you want "cab" to be 312?

Comment: That "character(0)" looks a bit odd.... Where did that come from?

Comment: BTW: `apply` works on matrices and data.frames, not vectors (as you are trying here). The vector-equivalent would be one of `sapply`, `lapply`, `tapply`, `vapply`, ...

Comment: @MikeH. Thanks, that works!

Comment: @Spacedman The character(0) is the NA.

Comment: @r2evens Thanks for the tip.